# PDF specification: how to specify encoding of core fonts?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to change a simple RAW PDF file to use a different font encoding (win-1257). This is the file:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 500 800] /Contents 6 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Font <</F1 5 0 R>>>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 44>>
stream
BT /F1 24 Tf 100 100 Td (ąčęėį šąčįžė)Tj ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000056 00000 n
0000000111 00000 n
0000000212 00000 n
0000000250 00000 n
0000000317 00000 n
trailer <</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
406
%%EOF
```

The line **BT /F1 24 Tf 100 100 Td (ąčęėį šąčįžė)Tj ET** here specifies a text stream with win-1257 encoded characters. The problem is, those characters are not displayed right in PDF.

How would i change this document for the characters to display correctly? Is there a simple way to just set the encoding? I suspect the **<< /Type /Encoding /Differences** is used to remap the characters, but, even if my suspicions are correct - this seems a bit too difficult.

Thanks for having a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
[...]
BT /F1 24 Tf 100 100 Td (ąčęėį šąčįžė)Tj ET
```

> How would I change this document for the characters to display correctly?

In addition to **/Encoding** dictionaries with **/Differences** most likely being the simplest way to set the encoding as @Xinwang already illuminated, I want to point out that you may have some additional problems: Not all of your characters might have a single associated glyph in **/Helvetica** or any other of the core Standard 14 Fonts!

Cf. the specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf); section 9.6.2.2 names the core fonts a conforming PDF viewer must have available and refers to annex D for details. In that annex you read:

> D.2, "Latin Character Set and Encodings", describes the entire character set for the Adobe standard Latin-text fonts. This character set shall be supported by the Times, Helvetica, and Courier font families, which are among the standard 14 predefined fonts;

... and if you compare the table in D.2 with your character selection, you'll find that e.g. there are only the following varieties of the lowercase letter **a**:

```
a a
á aacute
â acircumflex
ä adieresis
æ ae
à agrave
å aring
ã atilde
```

*Thus, the standard does not require a PDF viewer to provide a single glyph representation of your **ą**!*

There is a glyph in that table, though, which might be used in combination with the **a** glyph to build an **ą**:

```
˛ ogonek
```

Thus, you might need to use two characters, **a** and **˛**, in the content stream to display a **ą**, maybe even with some correction of the distance between them required.

The situation is similar for all your special characters.

*Thus, for your PDFs with an **ą** (or any other of your special characters) from Helvetica to be properly displayed on all viewers, you probably will need to change the content stream anyhow.*

That being said, the Adobe Helvetica font seems to know a glyph named **aogonek**; thus, if you don't care for all PDF viewers but the major one suffices, *you might get away with **merely** adding **/Encoding** dictionaries with **/Differences**!*

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I finally came to the same conclusion that adobe's standard fonts simply don't have glyphs that i need, even though Helvetica font on my system supports all sorts of interesting characters.

Answer (score 3):

Using `/Difference` should be simplest way. Other solution includes:

1. Re-encode the string in Tj command.
2. Craft the font by yourself (much much complex).

Comment: If the OP creates the "raw PDF" himself, too, re-encoding should also be easy. Essentially, though, those three items are the options.

Comment: I've tried using iconv to convert from UTF-8 to CP1257 (in PHP), but the output was not as expected